# Command called only on creation but not after button click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have window with `ICommand SaveCommand` which saves input data. Problem is that this command called only in moment of creation, but not after button click.

In ViewModel:

```
public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new SaveCommand(DataManager.Type.House, model);
        }
    }
```

Command:

```
class SaveCommand : ICommand
    {
        IModel model;
        DataManager.Type type;
        public SaveCommand(DataManager.Type type, IModel model)
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.model = model;
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case DataManager.Type.Book:
                    DataManager.AddBook((Book)model);
                    break;
                case DataManager.Type.Author:
                    DataManager.AddAuthor((Author)model);
                    break;
                case DataManager.Type.House:
                    DataManager.AddHouse((House)model);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

In XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="saveButton" 
                Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}" Content="_Save"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Path=AllPropertiesValid}" Click="SaveButton_Click"/>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class AddHouse : Window
    {
        public AddHouse()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new HouseViewModel();
        }

        protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
            base.OnClosing(e);
        }

        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, but it works fine here, i have removed the `SaveCommand constructor` as i dont have `IModel` and `DataManager`

Comment: By "this command called only in moment of creation" you mean that constructor is called during binding? I thought that `Command`s are supposed to replace `Click` events? Try removing the event handler

Comment: I'm find issue, it's was mine stupid error, sorry, i have  some code which takes data from dictionary inside `SaveCommand` property and key was `null` and i find this problem only when look through output. Now i know that errors in such style i can find only in output not in runtime error window message.